# Items in List View get affected when applying matchedGeometryEffect to views inside the List View - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

I'm trying to transition from the main view to a second view with animation using `.matchedGeometryEffect` but for some reason, if I apply the `.matchedGeometryEffect` directly to `Text(item.name)` only one item is visible, the rest of them get hidden. If I apply the `.matchedGeometryEffect` directly to the `List` all items show and I get the animation when it moves to the second view but is not the effect I'm looking for, I get a better effect when I apply  `.matchedGeometryEffect` to `Text(item.name)`.

Any idea why most items in the List disappear when I apply `.matchedGeometryEffect` to `Text(item.name)`?

#### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showEditView = false
    @State var selectedItem:Item?
    @Namespace var editViewAnaimation
    
    let items = [Item(name: "Fork", symbolName: "fork.knife"),
                Item(name: "Hammer", symbolName: "hammer.fill"),
                Item(name: "Lightbulb", symbolName: "lightbulb.fill")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showEditView{
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation{
                        showEditView.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.square.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                })
                EditView( editViewAnaimation: editViewAnaimation, selectedItem: selectedItem!)
            }else{
                List(items, id:\.self){ item in
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: item.symbolName)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        Text(item.name)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                           /// some items disappear when applied here, why?
                           //.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "name", in: editViewAnaimation)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedItem = item
                        withAnimation{
                            showEditView.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                /// all items show when applied here but not the effect I want
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "name", in: editViewAnaimation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### EDIT VIEW

```
struct EditView: View {
    var editViewAnaimation: Namespace.ID
    let selectedItem:Item
    @State var nameInput = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            TextField("name", text: $nameInput)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "name", in: editViewAnaimation)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear{
            nameInput = selectedItem.name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same id for all the `Text`s. This means that *every* `Text`'s frame would match. The "Fork" text would match "Hammer", and would also match "Lightbulb". All of them would be on top of one another, so you only see one text.

You should put the `matchedGeometryEffect` modifier on the `Text`s, and give an appropriate id to each of them. For example, you can use the name of the item as the id:

```
Text(item.name)
    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.name, in: editViewAnaimation)
```

```
TextField("name", text: $nameInput)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedItem.name, in: editViewAnaimation)
```

You only want the "Fork" `Text` to match the "Fork" `TextField`, the "Hammer" `Text` to match the "Hammer" `TextField` etc.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense a lot of sense!  It did the trick. Thanks a lot.